# How to embed Google weather rich card in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, embed, google-search, google-rich-snippets

How can I embed a Google rich card for weather section in my WordPress site?

Screenshot from Google Search: [Weather rich card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anHFh.png)

Is that available to embed something like this details provided by Google on the search engine on my site?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to display the Google Rich Card that you have linked, however there are a number of different options that would give you similar results.

1) Use any number of [WordPress weather plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=weather) that are available, like [Weather Underground plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wunderground/).

2) Use a [Free Weather Widget](http://www.accuweather.com/en/free-weather-widgets) from [AccuWeather.com](http://www.accuweather.com/)